# re-render single datatable row

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

i have a dynamic form based on `dataTable`, nested inside another `dataTable`.

on selecting a row from nested `dataTable` i'd like to update corresponding row from parent `dataTable` using `<p:ajax>`

```
<h:form id="form">

    <h:dataTable var="field" value="#{testBean.propertyList}" varStatus="status">

        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{field.label}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="app-grid" rendered="#{field.toOne}">
                <h:panelGroup id="value">
                    <h:outputText value="#{testBean.entity[field.name]}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton id="button" type="button" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search"/>
                    <p:overlayPanel for="button" my="left bottom" at="left bottom" widgetVar="panel_#{field.name}">
                        <p:dataTable
                            id="table" 
                            value="#{field.selectableModel}" 
                            selection="#{testBean.entity[field.name]}" 
                            selectionMode="single" 
                            var="item" 
                            rows="10"
                            paginator="true" 
                            paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
                            paginatorPosition="bottom"
                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                            currentPageReportTemplate="{totalRecords} records found"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

                            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":???:value" oncomplete="panel_#{field.name}.hide()"/>
                            <p:column headerText="entity">#{item}</p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:overlayPanel>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

the problem is that generated component tree does not have repeated explicit child components for `dataTable`:

```
<HtmlForm enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="form" inView="true" prependId="true" rendered="true" submitted="false" transient="false">
    <HtmlDataTable border="-2147483648" first="0" id="j_idt101" inView="true" rendered="true" rowIndex="-1" rowStatePreserved="false" rows="0" transient="false" var="field">
        <UIColumn id="j_idt103" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
            <HtmlOutputLabel escape="true" id="j_idt120" inView="true" rendered="true" style="" transient="false"/>
        </UIColumn>
        <UIColumn id="j_idt121" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
            <HtmlPanelGrid border="-2147483648" columns="2" id="j_idt122" inView="true" rendered="false" styleClass="app-grid" transient="false">
                <HtmlPanelGroup id="value" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
                    <HtmlOutputText escape="true" id="j_idt227" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/>
                </HtmlPanelGroup>
                <HtmlPanelGroup id="j_idt117" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
                    <CommandButton ajax="true" async="false" disabled="false" escape="true" global="true" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search" iconPos="left" id="button" immediate="false" inView="true" inline="false" partialSubmit="true" readonly="false" rendered="true" transient="false" type="button"/>
                    <OverlayPanel appendToBody="false" at="left bottom" dynamic="false" for="button" id="j_idt228" inView="true" my="left bottom" rendered="true" transient="false" widgetVar="panel_">
                        <DataTable currentPageReportTemplate="{totalRecords} records found" draggableColumns="false" editable="false" emptyMessage="No records found." filterEvent="keyup" first="0" id="table" inView="true" lazy="false" liveScroll="false" pageLinks="10" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rendered="true" resizableColumns="false" rowIndex="-1" rowStatePreserved="false" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" scrollHeight="-2147483648" scrollRows="0" scrollWidth="-2147483648" scrollable="false" selectionMode="single" sortOrder="ascending" transient="false" var="item">
                            <Column colspan="1" disabledSelection="false" filterBy="false" filterMatchMode="startsWith" filterMaxLength="2147483647" filterPosition="bottom" headerText="entity" id="j_idt229" inView="true" rendered="true" resizable="true" rowspan="1" transient="false" width="-1">
                                #{item}
                            </Column>
                        </DataTable>
                    </OverlayPanel>
                </HtmlPanelGroup>
            </HtmlPanelGrid>
        </UIColumn>
    </HtmlDataTable>
</HtmlForm>
```

for this reason i'm thinking about using `<c:forEach>` instead of parent `dataTable` to make every row explicit in component tree.

but the first problem is that `testBean` is `@ViewScoped`...

and the second is that using `<c:forEach>` causes a `Java Heap Space` error...

some hint?

Comment: It does not create child components per row by performance reasons. Instead, the state is handled internally, but if you have the right clientId, JSF will retrieve the component in the right state. The trick is get the client id from the parent component but remember dataTable is NamingContainer, so you need to lookup the ids from the parent one (using ':' as prefix, don't remember exactly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the outer table a fixed `id`.

```
<h:dataTable id="table" ...>
```

Then you'll be able to use

```
<p:ajax ... update=":form:table:value" />
```